# using or "|" operator for statements in java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean-logic

Suppose I have an array a[] , if I want to change the value of a[i] and change it to zero , I can do it by using temp variable like.

```
int temp = a[i];
a[i] = 0;
```

But I came across a code similar to this

```
int temp = a[i] | (a[i] = 0);
```

I had hard time understanding this. Please explain does it work? Is it a good practice to use similar type of code ?

Comment: I would say it is bad practice, as it is looks like a non-obvious trick, which will confuse somebody reading the code (like you!)

Comment: Minor point: the fact that it's an array isn't relevant. It would be just the same for `int temp = a | (a = 0);`, if `a` were a primitive `int`.

Comment: If you want to compact the code, just put both statements on the same line: `int temp = a[i]; a[i] = 0;`. Not great, but infinitely better than that weird construct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the straightforward code is to grab a value from an array and set its location in the array to `0`.

Let's see how the tricky code does it.

The `|` operator is the bitwise-or operator.  First, `a[i]` is evaluated, and whatever value is there is the left operand.  Next, the parentheses force `a[i] = 0` to be evaluated.  This sets the array element to `0` and the right operand of `|` is now `0`.  Performing a bitwise-or with the value `0` doesn't change the other value.  The value of the entire expression on the right of `temp =` is the original value of `a[i]`.  This has the effect of doing everything the straightforward code does, in one statement.

This code is tricky and it's not good practice, because it's confusing.  I would never use such a technique.